# How to read and store data from text file

Tags: vb.net

i'll Simplify my question as possible.

Now i have program with two buttons and one textbox

Button 1 = Open file dialog

Button 2 = Do some code with the file loaded then export it to the textbox

```
'Button 1'
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()

End Sub
```

How i can make button 2 read data as it was textbox and do some code with it then export to textbox1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is what you looking for?

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim textpath As New TextBox

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "TXT|*.txt"
        If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            textpath.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        If textpath.Text = Nothing Then
        Else
            TextBox1.Text = textpath.Text ' all text in .txt
            TextBox1.Text = textpath.Lines(0) ' text from lines 0=first line, 1= second line 2.3.4.......
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: so textpath is my content inside my txt ?

Comment: i want in button 2 to make some functions like making and put it in textbox how ican connect button 1 with button 2

Comment: i want button 1 for only browse and choosing file , button 2 export to textbox @dmpower007

Comment: check my updated code again, i test it just now and it's working fine sir

Comment: thanks @dmpower007 for your help , thing not added to my question i have for each loop when i try to add ` For Each line In textpath.Lines` give me error lines is not a member of String